# DryIoc: cannot register using Made

Tags: c#, dryioc

I'm using the DryIoc container at the moment.

In the documentation it is shown how to register using Made:

```
c.Register<Foo>(made: Made.Of(() => new Foo(Arg.Of<IDependency>())));
```

I like this very much, however in my case the compiler doesn't recognize the Made class.  If using Made is obsolete then what is an alternative?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin, The error is: "The name 'Made' does not exist in current context". I'm using .Net 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think the problem was that i had used dryioc 1.4.1 (nuget default at that moment). When i installed version 2.0.0-rc4 the problem gone.